# Where is the the official docs for the concept of "Tenant" of MinIO Operator?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minio

I'd like to use [MinIO Operator](https://github.com/minio/operator).

There's a concept of "Tenant".
https://github.com/minio/operator/tree/master/helm/tenant

What is it?

I couldn't find the official docs for its purpose and detailed concept.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tenant is a generic word not specific to minio, it usually refers to the user having full control over data privacy and performance. Check out below link for more information

[https://www.techtarget.com/searchdatamanagement/tip/5-key-elements-of-data-tenancy#:~:text=A%20data%20tenant%20is%20an,the%20customer%20of%20their%20service](https://www.techtarget.com/searchdatamanagement/tip/5-key-elements-of-data-tenancy#:%7E:text=A%20data%20tenant%20is%20an,the%20customer%20of%20their%20service).

To use minio you need to deploy operator and tenant where operator is responsible for managing and deploying these tenants. Once you deploy the operator you will see a loadbalancer in services pointing to minio console you can use that address and create a tenant with your required storage size.

**Note:** Before creating a tenant just make sure you already have a storage class in your Kubernetes cluster.